# Why aren't all functions virtual in C++?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

In C++, why aren't functions declared virtual in classes by default. I can't think of any reason why someone would not want them default. If they were all virtual, wouldn't save sometime for the programmer?

Comment: The `c++` has a concept of only paying for what you use. This would incur a cost for classes and structs that don't need virtual functions.

Comment: Functions should either be designed to be overridden, or shouldn't be virtual. "Everything virtual by default" is bad design.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili What do you think about everything should be const by default?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov • I think so, yes.  Because I agree with Kate Gregory in her presentation [What do we mean when we say nothing at all?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYVxGyido9g) about C++ having "all the defaults are wrong".  Alas, that ship has sailed.

Comment: Keep in mind that most compilers will create a table for virtual functions.  When the virtual function is called, a CPU instruction is used to load function address from the table and then call the function.  This was quite expensive in number of instruction cycles at one time.  Chains of virtual function calls were still expensive, when I last checked (a number of years ago).